# pine script to buy at previos candle of crossover

Tags: pine-script

I am with a weighted moving average crossover strategy ,i am trying to buy at the previous candle close of the crossover and to exit at the close of the candle after crossover can some buddy help me for this i want pine script for this

Comment: Could you elaborate? `buy at the previous candle close`  Do you mean put the order with the price of previous candle close or you literally want to fill the order at that previous bar?

Comment: to put the order at the previous candle whether it gets executed or not

Comment: The previous candle has been closed already, so you can't do with it anything.

Comment: i just want to open order

Comment: But the bar has been closed and there's no such price. You might just put an order with that price of the previous `close`, and if the current price gets back to that level of price, then the order will be filled.